# C++ vector.begin() and vector[0]

Tags: c++, vector

why this two line prints different addresses?

```
vector<int> v1{ 12,2,34 };
printf_s("%d -  0x%p\n", v1[0], &v1[0]);
printf_s("%d -  0x%p\n",*v1.begin(), v1.begin());
```

Values in this addresses are same but address itself is different.
Does it mean that there is two copy of the same array?

**EDIT**: In debug mode it prints different addresses, in release mode there are same addresses :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`v1.begin()` returns an `std::vector<int>::iterator`, which is not necessarily an address to `v1[0]`. In fact, attempting to print it out using `printf` gives me a warning:

> warning: format **'%p'** expects argument of type **'void*'**, but argument 3 has type **'std::vector::iterator`**

Unless you're sure that in your particular Standard Library implementation and with your current compilation options `std::vector<int>::iterator` is an alias for `int*`, the comparison is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you, now it's more clear, `&(*v1.begin()` and `&v1[0]` print same address.

Comment: @Person.Junkie But that's not the same thing as you has in the question.

Answer (score 2):

for a vector object v1:

`&V[0]` is the the address of first element of the object v1.

when we create an iterator e.g `vector<>::iterator iter` the `iter` itself is an other object as explain in this [document](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-iterators.html).

> Iterator: a pointer-like object that can be incremented with ++,
>   dereferenced with *, and compared against another iterator with !=.

I hope this reference manual answer your question in detail.